# Postgres Database in Azure VM not working properly

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-virtual-machine, wiki.js

We are using Ubuntu Azure VM. We have installed Postgres 16.1 in the VM for wiki.js application. All the things are working properly for few hours. later we are getting the issue in Postgres terminal and Postgres got down,

[image]

in Postgres log file as

[image]

The steps in below link resolved our issue temporarily.

[postgresql: Invalid data directory | Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092546/postgresql-invalid-data-directory-cant-open-pid-file-var-run-postgresql-10)

But again we are getting the same error after few hours. We dont know what is the issue. Please help us to understand the issue.

Comment: You are being hacked.  That big blob of base64 is a malware loader.  Rebuild the system, and this time use good passwords.  Or don't let people from the random internet even connect to the system.  Or both.

Comment: @jjanes we have deleted the  VM and created new VM and run wiki.js(this time we build the source code and generated docker image) and postgress database. Again same issue happened.

Comment: Try Disabling selinux. Change it from enforcing to disabled.
under /etc/selinux/config I can see in your error log it says selinux permission denied

Comment: Did you harden your security?  If all you do is rebuild your image but with the same weakness, you will just get hacked again.  When you say "same issue", does that only mean you can't connect, or is the same base64 blob showing up in the log file again?

Comment: @jjanes you are correct, the VM got hacked, now resolved the issue. Please find my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Azure VM got hacked because the default PostgreSQL port 5432 was exposed publicly.

Because of that malware file added. Refer [this](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/how-my-server-got-infected-with-a-crypto-mining-malware-and-how-i-fixed-it)

> a crypto mining malware that spreads by exploiting flaws in resources that are exposed to the public. Killing the process was of no use since the malware also adds a cron job to replicate itself so that it can’t be stopped.

[image]

Fixed the error by,

1. Created a new VM and installed Postgres
2. Strong password for Postgres database
3. Open port to specific IP address.